# Sequence find b so sequence is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For z$\in$C we have that z=1+i$\sqrt3$. We defined the sequence $a_n$=(b$*z)^n$. Then I have to find the value for b so $a_n$ is convergent for n$\in$N. Can anyone help with some ideas?
I have found the modulus:

|$_$|=($\sqrt b^2$+($\sqrt3)$$^2$)$^n$

How can I use the modulus to find for which b $a_n$ is convergent?

Comment: Try writing $z$ in polar form and seeing what $(bz)^n$ looks like.

Comment: I have found that z=2*(cos($\pi$/3)+isin($\pi$/3)). I don't actually see how I can use this?

Comment: That's not the polar form; the polar form is $2e^{\pi/3}$, and it's very easy to compute powers of this.

Comment: Your earlier post was closed. Why are you posting it again? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650942/sequences-convergent-find-value-for-b

Comment: Brian M. Scott: Thank you. You just forgot an "i". I will try to use this. But i don't know how? Should I use a "polar coordinate system"?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: we have $|z|=2.$ Thus $|a_n| =2^n |b|^n.$

Can you proceed ?